# How to Create a Linked List with Generics

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I'm trying to write my own Linked List class in Java using generics. The linked list should work with two different Node classes I have created. I want to be able to call methods of the node classes that is used in my Linked List, but obviously it doesn't work the way I am trying to do it. Each node class will have all of the same methods (and method names), but the methods for each will do different things. With this I have a few questions:

1) What is the "work around" (if any) to calling methods on generic type variables. In my case, I am trying to call methods of my node class from my linked list class.

2) How do I make sure the only two data types my Linked List can have are the two node classes I define?

3) Am I thinking about this completely wrong? i.e. Should I be doing this an entirely different way?

Here is a simplified version of the code.

```
public class Node1 {

    public int stuff1;
    public Node1 nextNode;

    Node1() {
        this.nextNode = null;
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("Node 1 did stuff");
    }

}

public class Node2 {

    public int stuff2;
    public Node2 nextNode;

    Node2() {
        this.nextNode = null;
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("Node 2 did other stuff");
    }

}

public class LinkedList<T>{

    public T first; // do I need to construct/instantiate this too?

    public void doStuff() {
        first.doStuff;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList<Node1> node1 = new LinkedList<Node1>;
        LinkedList<Node2> node2 = new LinkedList<Node2>;
        node1.doStuff();
        node2.doStuff();
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make node1 and node2 extend a common abstract class, so you can accept only that class with something like `T extends abstractClass`

Comment: Just a thought (discard if not suitable for your purpose): You could have an abstract `Node` class with everything a `Node` needs, only the `doStuff` method would be abstract, with different implementations in the concrete subclasses `Node1` and `Node2`. And your list class could be declared `public class LinkedList<T extends Node>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example:

1. Define an `interface` specifying `doStuff()`, call it for example `CanDoStuff`
2. Have both classes implement the interface
3. Define the `LinkedList` class as `LinkedList<T extends CanDoStuff>`

However, using generics applies more if you wanted to define a `LinkedList<Node1>` containing only `Node1` elements and/or a `LinkedList<Node2>`.  if you really want to limit the list contents for ever to be only those two classes, you don't need to use generics at all.  Where you have `T` in your `LinkedLIst` substitute `CanDoStuff` (and make the class non-generic).

In that case when you retrieve elements from the list they'll come back as `CanDoStuff` and if you want to invoke a method specific to one of the concrete classes you'll need to downcast the reference, unless you can move the method declaration into `CanDoStuff` and implement it in both `Node1` and `Node2`.

Comment: "Where you have T in your  LinkedLIst substitute CanDoStuff (and make the class non-generic)." Would that just mean making the first line of the linked list class be: public class LinkedList {, and all other uses of 'T' be replaced with CanDoStuff?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.